# PHP XML file filter on match

Tags: php, xml

I am having a heck of a time getting this working...

What I want to do is filter a xml file by a city (or market in this case).

This is the xml data.

```
<itemset>
<item>
<id>2171</id>
<market>Vancouver</market>
<url>http://</url></item>
<item>
<id>2172</id>
<market>Toronto</market>
<url>http://</url></item>
<item>
<id>2171</id>
<market>Vancouver</market>
<url>http://</url></item>
```

This is my code...

```
<?php
$source = 'get-xml-feed.php.xml';

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($source);

$result = $xml->xpath('//item/[contains(market, \'Toronto\')]');

while(list( , $node) = each($result)) {
    echo '//Item/[contains(Market, \'Toronto\')]',$node,"\n";
}

?>
```

If I can get this working I would like to access each element, item[0], item[1] base on filtered results.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this implements what you are looking for using XPath:

```
<?php
$source = file_get_contents('get-xml-feed.php.xml');

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($source);

foreach ($xml as $node)
{
    $row = simplexml_load_string($node->asXML());
    $result = $row->xpath("//item/market[.='Toronto']");
    if ($result[0])
    {
        var_dump($row);
    }
}

?>
```

As another answer mentioned, unless you are wed to the use of XPath it's probably more trouble than it's worth for this application: just load the XML and treat the result as an array.

Comment: I think we may be trying to get the parent node that contains the specific node. For that you would need this xpath expressions: '//item/market[.='Toronto']/..'

Answer (score 0):

I propose using [simplexml_load_file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php). The learning curve is less step than using the specific XML objects + XPath. It returns an object in the format you descibe.

Try this and you'll see what I mean:

```
<?php
$source = 'get-xml-feed.php.xml';

$xml = simplexml_load_file($source);

var_dump($xml);
?>
```

There is also [simplexml_load_string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php) if you just have an XML snippet.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$source = 'get-xml-feed.php.xml';

//$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($source);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTMLFile($source);
$xml = simplexml_import_dom($dom);  

$result = $xml->xpath("//item/market[.='Toronto']/..");

while(list( , $node) = each($result)) {
   print_r($node);
}

?>
```

This will get you the parent nodeset when it contains a node with "Toronto" in it. It returns $node as a simplexml element so you will have to deal with it accordingly (I just printed it as an array).